# Did not record an invocation in OCMStub/OCMExpect/OCMReject

Tags: objective-c, xctest, ocmock

I'm trying to mock a Singleton class in one of my unit tests. The way I'm creating my mock is like this:

```
MySingletonController *mockController = OCMClassMock([MySingletonController class]);
OCMStub([MySingletonController sharedController]).andReturn(mockController);
```

The complete error that I got is:

```
Did not record an invocation in OCMStub/OCMExpect/OCMReject.
Possible causes are:
- The receiver is not a mock object.
- The selector conflicts with a selector implemented by OCMStubRecorder/OCMExpectationRecorder. (NSInternalInconsistencyException).
```

One important thing to mention is that the shared instance is not something that instantiates the class, it just returns a variable. That variable is assigned during the init (which occurs) during the nib load. But I really doubt that this has something to do with the problem.

I'm not completely aware of what could cause the `OCM` error that I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how I was declaring the `OCMStub`. My `sharedController` method is a `class` method. Then it needs to be declared differently for `OCMStub`.

```
MySingletonController *mockController = OCMClassMock([MySingletonController class]);
OCMStub(ClassMethod([(id)mockController sharedController])).andReturn(mockController);
```

After changing my code as above, the test started to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The second line should be as follows:

```
OCMStub([mockController sharedController]).andReturn(mockController);
```